# Convert array to object - first and last of array to key and value of object

Tags: javascript

How could I convert an array that constantly changes length into an object where the first element in the array becomes the objects key and the last element is the keys value. for example `["queen", "king", "charles", "beyonce"]` needs to become `{queen: "beyonce"}`.

Comment: `var obj = {};`
`obj[arr[0]] = arr[arr.length-1];`

Answer (score 0):

Given array "a" you can do:

```
var b= {}

b[a[0]] = a[a.length-1]]
```

You'll want to test to make sure the array has length of 2 or more before doing that and handle cases where it doesn't in some way that makes sense to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just write an object literal, with a computed property:

```
{[a[0]]: a[a.length-1]}
```